# how to fill empty dates in Spark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I have an order table, I can sum daily order accumulate amount like below:

```
date    amount

2017/5/1    1000

2017/5/5    2000
```

but i want to get :

```
date    amount

2017/5/1    1000

2017/5/2    1000

2017/5/3    1000

2017/5/4    1000

2017/5/5    2000
```

there is no order between **2017-05-02** and **2017-05-04**,so the amount stays 1000.How can i do this ?

Comment: What's your input dataset? Do you want to generate missing rows for days when there was no orders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below snippet should work... here we perform a left-join between our data set with another dataframe that basically list all dates between our start and end date.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = Seq(("2017/5/1", 1000), ("2017/5/5", 1000)).toDF("day","value")

val df2 = Seq("2017/5/1","2017/5/2","2017/5/3","2017/5/4","2017/5/5").toDF("date")

val result = df2
      .join(df1, df1("day") === df2("date"), "left_outer")
      .withColumn("value", when($"value".isNull,0).otherwise($"value"))
      .select("date","value")
      .withColumn("value", sum($"value").over(Window.orderBy($"date")))

result.show()
{"level": "WARN ", "timestamp": "2017-05-22 05:01:28,693", "classname": "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WindowExec", "body": "No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation."}
+--------+-----+
|    date|value|
+--------+-----+
|2017/5/1| 1000|
|2017/5/2| 1000|
|2017/5/3| 1000|
|2017/5/4| 1000|
|2017/5/5| 2000|
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: @leiyu if this solves your problem can you please accept the answer?